# Gimbal geofence

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, gimbal

I am using Gimbal SDK. 
When I create a new place. It is created on device but not on gimbal manager.

I am confused about this issue. Why this is not updated to server.
I checked with the key and documentation also.

Thanks in advance.,

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean when you create it through your application? It says in the [documentation](https://gimbal.com/doc/Gimbal_SDK_for_iOS.pdf) (page 15), that when you create a geofence in the device it is not available on the Gimbal Manager.

Answer (score 2):

The gimbal manager doesn't handle this. When you create a place on your device is *a private place*.
Geofence Places on gimbal manager are public ones, any one can access them.